# MVC5 StringLength validation failing on int

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

i have the following validations specified for an int field.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.ResponseRequired)]
        [Digits(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.DigitsOnly)]
        [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.InvalidLength)]
        public int? Code { get; set; }
```

When i take out the StringLength then the post is successful. With it, i get 500 exception:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'**

What is going on here? Do i need to write a custom one for int? In this case, i just want to make sure that the user is entering 6 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String length isnt really valid for an int, though?

What is it that you are trying to achieve? That the input is greater than 99,999?

Then you can use:

```
[Range(100000,int.MaxValue)]
```

Comment: We are sending the code to the users, it is 6 digit long. All i want is to check that they are entering 6 digits.

Comment: I have changed it to regex [RegularExpression("^{6}$", ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.InvalidLength)], but now my ModelState.IsValid is coming back as false.

Comment: I must be missing the point. If you get an integer input that is greater that 99,999 (as the above code enforces) then you have at least 6 digits. You could always change it to Range(100000,999990) to ensure EXACTLY 6 digits....

Comment: hmmm... never thought that some thing like this could be done here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Range or RegularExpression for control your digits length.

```
Range[0,999999]  
Range[100000,999999]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{6}")]
```